# Using Parse to make an iOS Social Network App?

Tags: ios, social-networking

I want to make an iOS Scocial Network, almost like Facebook. But I only do it to test my Objective C programming skills so it wont be massive like Facebook (though it will have all features that Facebook has).
What I want to ask is:
Can I only use my Objective C knowledge to build my front-end app and use Parse Services (Parse.com) to build my back-end? Or I need some tools, knowledge etc...?

Again, I do not make a very very big iOS Social Network app like Facebook but I do a smaller one that has all features Facebook has.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Objective-C to create the app and use Parse.com to host your data. You can use the Parse SDK to allow the app to easily access the backend data. It will work well (depending on how well you design the Parse data storage) and you won't need to write any (or much) backend code.

Comment: I have been making a detailed plan to develop my app. I googled a lot and I just realize it seems I wont have a complete chat feature with only Parse. I need another services like Pubnub, Pusher etc... Could you give me some advice to do that?

Comment: Parse.com offers push notifications, this is a better option for notifying users that they have received messages as it does not require the app to be running in the background.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From what I read here (http://www.quora.com/Parse-cloud-backend/Is-it-possible-to-use-Parse-com-for-realtime-chat-like-Socket-io) I assume that I can't get realtime without using an external solution. Im curious about your advices on this situation. :D

Comment: Ok, yes, from that article if you want user online true real-time then a solution like Pubnub makes sense. Using Parse you would need to poll the server for changes periodically to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Ok thx. So 1 more question, do you any tutorial, example about how to combining Parse and Pubnub :D. I have googled it but dont have.

Comment: You're unlikely to find one, they don't really connect. You'd use Parse to manage the users and store the messages + friends / contacts persistently and Pubnub would be separate and just for real-time message passing while users were online with each other.

Comment: I dont absolutely understand it. So if you dont mind, could you talk more about how to use Pubnub to make it is "real-time" cause I dont even know what exactly Pubnub wuold do on the chat feature. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[parse.com/tutorials](https://www.parse.com/tutorials) actually has a couple tutorials that would be very helpful in creating your social app. It may even be exactly what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Parse is the way to go. You might want to check out Helios and Stackmob as well. They do the same thing as parse. However, I like Parse much better because of it's documentation.

Happy learning.